# ObservableQueue

Tags: c#, .net, immutability, observer-pattern

I'm looking for feedback on this.

```
public sealed class ObservableQueue<T> : IObservable<T>, IDisposable
{
    private readonly object _lock = new object();
    private ImmutableQueue<T> _processQueue = ImmutableQueue<T>.Empty;
    private ImmutableList<IObserver<T>> _observers = ImmutableList<IObserver<T>>.Empty;
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _active = new ManualResetEvent(true);
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _itemEnqueued = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private readonly ManualResetEvent _completed = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private readonly Thread _thread;
    private bool _disposed;

    public ObservableQueue()
    {
        _thread = new Thread(Execute);
        _thread.IsBackground = true;
        _thread.Start();
    }

    public void Enqueue(T value)
    {
        ImmutableInterlocked.Enqueue(ref _processQueue, value);
        _itemEnqueued.Set();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        if (observer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("observer");
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _observers, _observers.Add(observer));
        return new Subscription(this, observer);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_disposed)
                return;
            _active.Reset();
            _itemEnqueued.Set();
            _completed.WaitOne();
            _active.Dispose();
            _itemEnqueued.Dispose();
            _completed.Dispose();
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    private void Execute()
    {
        try
        {
            while (_active.WaitOne(1))
            {
                if (!_itemEnqueued.WaitOne())
                    continue;

                T value;
                while (ImmutableInterlocked.TryDequeue(ref _processQueue, out value))
                    OnNext(value);

                _itemEnqueued.Reset();
            }
            OnCompleted();
            _completed.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnError(ex);
        }
    }

    private void OnCompleted()
    {
        foreach (var observer in _observers)
        {
            try
            {
                observer.OnCompleted();
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }

    private void OnNext(T value)
    {
        foreach (var observer in _observers)
        {
            try
            {
                observer.OnNext(value);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnError(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnError(Exception ex)
    {
        foreach (var observer in _observers)
        {
            try
            {
                observer.OnError(ex);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
    }

    private sealed class Subscription : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ObservableQueue<T> _instance;
        private readonly IObserver<T> _observer;

        public Subscription(ObservableQueue<T> instance, IObserver<T> observer)
        {
            _instance = instance;
            _observer = observer;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref _instance._observers, _instance._observers.Remove(_observer));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The queue is dependent on the subscribers; throws errors based on subscriber state. And in order to be useful the subscribers must depend on it. There's significant afferent and efferent  coupling in the implementation. Perhaps not a good thing.

An alternative would be to write to a stream or bus or log and let clients read from the stream according to their needs. Adding a reader interface would let the subscribers know what the queue is committed to doing...and what it is not committed to (e.g. how does it flush? when full does it drop oldest events or refuse new ones? what does it do when it is empty? etc.).

Answer (score 5):

Threads??? Once you have threads in your code, your code becomes obsolete even if it was written 2 seconds ago. `Tasks` are the way to go, and you can easily replace your code by a single Task that keeps running and a function that accepts Tasks

```
 async Task<T> EnqueueTask(Func<T> taskFunc)
 {
   var task = new Task<T>(func);
   // enqueue it and start executing it
   T result = await task;
   return result
 }
```

Now, you can use `continuations` to fire your events

```
 task.ContinueWith(()=> fire events )
```

And you can have the main Task that listens for items being enqueued

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // listen for tasks being added to the queue
        }
    }
```

I wouldn't start this Task in the constructor as you doing with the `Thread`,thats quite dangerous, I would rather have a method called Start that does the heavy stuff where I am sure its gonna get called after the object got constructed properly.

**ADVICE:** Such a data structure is reasonably hard to implement properly, I would try to find something implemented and tested.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>    try
>    {
>        observer.OnCompleted();
>    }
>    catch
>    {
>
>    }
> ```

Empty catch blocks??? Are you ***sure*** that's what you want to do?

> Empty catch statements can be just as bad, depending on the MSIL code
> that your language generates. C# turns an empty catch statement into
> catch(System.Object) which means you end up catching all
> exceptions—even non-CLS compliant exceptions. VB is better-behaved,
> turning an empty catch statement into catch e as System.Exception
> which limits you to catching CLS compliant exceptions.

[*Why empty catch is bad. - MSDN*](https://web.archive.org/web/20160111044154/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/dotnet/archive/2009/02/19/why-catch-exception-empty-catch-is-bad.aspx)

You should either be specific about what exceptions you want to catch, or not catch them at all.

If you're absolutely positive this is what you want, you should at least leave a comment indicating that the empty catches are intentional.

I also recommend reading this SO question on the topic for further insight.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/16715664/3198973